# What is the maximum number of recipients for email sending in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to send emails to all the customers using Laravel Mailable. I have following mail structure.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

/**
 * Class BroadcastEmail
 * @package App\Mail
 */
class BroadcastEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $title
     * @param $body
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($title, $body)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->title)->view('emails.broadcast')->with(['body' => $this->body]);
    }
}
```

I have used following code to send the email.

```
Mail::to($recipients)->send(new BroadcastEmail($title, $message));
```

Here, `$recipients` variable is the array of customer emails. It's size can be above 10,000 in the future. What is the maximum size of the `$recipients` array that Mail Facade can process to send emails ?

I have already read the laravel mail documentation and unable to figure out. Any Kind of suggestions and helps are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried ` implements ShouldQueue` ? Also you can send email to a collection of users

Comment: @ Prafulla Kumar Sahu its not about queue. he is asking for number of recipients which can be send in single request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel will not limit the number of recipiets. The limit is set by the mail provider, but there is no standard for this.

Most providers allow up to 100 recipients (To + CC + BCC), but there are providers that allow more. However, if you send a mail with over 100 recipients to a mailbox that does not allow this many recipients, the mail might not arrive.

The best solution for something like this is to send mails in batches of small numbers. This will allow faster processing and makes sure the mails arrive correctly.

Comment: Also make sure to not send the email addresses of customers to other customers, i.e. do not use `to` but `bcc` if at all.

Comment: @Namoshek, I have to send email as individual notification email so bcc not work for me ;)

Comment: So, I have to make chunks of emails with size like 100 and iterate over the total chunks ?

Comment: I'm confused. If the email is _individual_, how are you **broadcasting** it?

Comment: @Namoshek, sorry for that, I mean same email is sent to multiple customers. I am not familiar about bcc and cc usage

Comment: You should definitely use bcc in that case. If you add all customers in the `to` field, all customers will see the other customers email addresses and you have a huge security hole.

Comment: @Jerodev Okay, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Number of emails is not fixed. It all depends upon your server specifications. The emails will continue to send until or unless php.ini halts it due to some configuration. So, there is no number fixed for sending emails.

Comment: _It all depends upon your server specifications..._ Really? Read over the accepted answer again

Comment: Yes, really, daily our tool sends email to all employees of the company which is around 1000 users. I hope this clears you doubt. I myself have tested by sending emails to 400 users simaltaneously.

Comment: _I hope this clears you doubt...._ No! This has nothing to do with my comment above

Comment: Sorry, I work on dedicated servers not on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing same problems with testing emails using mailtrap in my project. Here's a quick workaround on sending mails on your localhost.

In my Listener, where I send emails to users (more than 400 users), I used Laravel's `report` helper and `try-catch` loop, where the emails send function won't fail if one of the mails did't go through.

```
try{
   Mail::to($user)->send(new NewsEmail($user, $news));
}catch (\Exception $e){
   report ($e)
}
```

The  report helper function allows you to quickly report an exception using your exception handler's report method without rendering an error page. More about this in official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#report-method).

Comment: Well, this logic was more complex in my project. Instead of report() method, I added a function to store all the failed emails in database table. So, when the email failed to send for some reason, it was stored in a table with exception message, and next email would queue.

Answer (score 0):

Send the emails in chunks of 50 or fewer, since postmark and other mailers do not accept more than 50 recipients at a time.

For example:

```php
// Send emails in batches of 25 users at a time.
$users->chunk(25)->each(function ($userBatch) use ($customMessage) {
  Mail::queue(new NotifyUsers($userBatch, $customMessage));
});
```

Comment: Some have limits far lower than 50. I've had to deal with limits of only 10 at a time with certain providers.